# How to create a submenu in django with(parent and children)?

Tags: python, django

I try to create menu with submenu hierarchy. 
My models.py

```
class Category(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', on_delete=models.CASCADE,db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('parent', 'slug',))
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def get_slug_list(self):
        try:
            ancestors = self.get_ancestors(include_self=True)
        except:
            ancestors = []
        else:
            ancestors = [ i.slug for i in ancestors]
        slugs = []
        for i in range(len(ancestors)):
            slugs.append('/'.join(ancestors[:i+1]))
        return slugs

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

In my ListView I have such query

```
Category.objects.all()
```

And now I want to display all of my parent object on the main page of index.html and in submenu consequently children for each specific parent. How can I do it?

Comment: So what you are saying is that you have a query set from `Category.objetcs.all()` that is in your template (index.html), from which you want to display the parents and children?

Comment: yes, I can iterate it via for i in category_all , i or i.parent. But I don't know how to structure that

Comment: Could you please clarify by what you mean when you say you don't know how to structure it?

Comment: I want to get structure like this (parent1 -children1, children2)  (parent2 - children3, children4).  {% for x in category %}{{ x }}{% if x.parent %}{{ x.parent }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}  This repeats all categories but I first level I need only parrent and in dropdown children. Don't know how to structure it in template.